# Perl Regexp Extract string from nested brackets

Tags: perl, parsing, nested, extract

I am trying to extract some information from a file that has the following content:

```
field {
    a:"bb"
    c:"dd"
    field_param {
        x:"xx"
        y:"yy"
    }
    other_param {
        z:"ee"
    }
    abc_param {
        x: { abc: "value"; cfg:"value"}
        ze: "value"
    }
}

field {
    a:"bb"
    c:"dd"
    field_param {
        x:"xx"
        y:"yy"
    }
    others_param {
        z:"ee"
    }
}
```

There are more `fields` like above, in a text file. Not all the `fields` are the same format, some have different params.

I am trying to extract for each `field`, to consider it as object with variables and values. The problem is the nested {}
I do not know how to extract the values between {} after splitting all the file in `fields`. I am taking than, `field` by `field` but it does not work to extract the things that are between brackets, if I want to do it recursively.

Until now I did something like:

```
 open(FILE,"myfile.txt")
    while(<FILE>)
    {
    $text .=$_;
    }
    close(FILE)
    my @fields= split /fields/,$text;
    for my $field(@fields)
    {
    my($extracted,$remainder)=extracted_bracketed($field,'{}');
    }
```

But this extracts only what is in field. I want to do it somehow recursive.

Anybody has any idea?

Comment: Are you having a problem with your parser? What problem? Where's your code?

Comment: I'd suggest _not_ using something that looks like JSON, but isn't. That's nasty. Otherwise I'd suggest you elaborate on what problem you're having. Because you have a recursive data structure, you may want a recursive parser.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a parser, and it sounds like you know nothing about parsing. This language is not all dissimilar to JSON, so I recommend you copy JSON::PP and adapt it to your language.

Alternatively, use a parser builder such as [Marpa](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Marpa::R2).