# How to extract some specific information from a file in perl?

Tags: perl

```
## some lines 
## cell (a) { area : 0.898; power: 0.867; 
      ....(some parameters values)
   } 
   pin(a1) { power: 0.767; (some more parameters specific to pins)
   timing() { 
      ## again some parameters value....
   }
```

My file contains approx 300 such cells and these cells are in between the files. I want to parse the file and what to know all the variable parameters, i tried following code but it is of no use

```
 while (defined($line=<$fh>)) {
     if ($line =~ /cell \(\w+\) \{/../cell \(\w+\) \{/) {
         print $result "$line \n";
     }
 }
```

I want to get the values inside { } also but , dont know how to get as i have parenthesis inside parenthesis in my code. Please help.

---

Thank u all for the help..I wrote a code to take into account of scalar attributes(ignoring all the attributes inside parenthesis.) BUt I am facing a very weird problem. I am facing problem with if ($line =~ /cell (\w/../cell (\w/) in my code. For the first file, it detects the line which has cell ( field and starts from there, but for the second file it starts from the first line itself.

```
open $result_file1, ">", "file1.txt";
open $result_file2, ">", "file2.txt";
open $fl1, $file1; open $fl2, $file2;

sub file_reader {
    ($fh, $indx) = @_;
    $count = 0;
    undef @temp; undef @pram;
    while (defined($line=<$fh>)) {      
        if ($line =~ /cell \(\w/../cell \(\w/) {
        if ($indx == "1") {print $result_file1 "$line\n";}
        if ($indx == "2") {print $result_file2 "$line\n";}
        if ($line =~ /cell \(\w/) {
            @temp = split (' ', $line);}
        if ($line =~ /\{/) {
            $count += 1;}
        if ($line =~ /\}/) {
            $count = $count - 1; }  
        if (($line =~ /:/) and ($count == 1)) { 
            @pram = split (':', $line);         
            if ($indx == "1") {$file1{$temp[1]}{@pram[1]} = @pram[2];}
            elsif ($indx == "2") { $file2{$temp[1]}{@pram[1]} = @pram[2];}
} }}
close $fh;}

file_reader($fl1, "1");
file_reader($fl2, "2");
```

A piece of output of file1 :
    cell (AND2X1) {

```
    cell_footprint : "AND2X1 ";

    area : 7.3728 ;

    cell_leakage_power : 3.837209e+04;

    driver_waveform_rise : "preDrv";

    driver_waveform_fall : "preDrv";

    pg_pin (VDD) {

        voltage_name : "VDD";

        pg_type : "primary_power";

    }

    pg_pin (VSS) {

        voltage_name : "VSS";

        pg_type : "primary_ground";

    }
    .......
```

A piece of output of file2:

```
/**********************************************************************

****                                                               ****

****  The data contained in the file is created for educational    **** 

****  and training purposes only and are not recommended           ****

****  for fabrication                                              ****

****                                                               ****

***********************************************************************

****                                                               ****
```

Why it is not able to apply that range if condition for my second file?

Comment: We need some code and some representative sample data to be able to answer. "Something like" isn't good enough - it doesn't need to contain real values, but is MUST have a correct structure. And some working code that illustrates the problem. And a desired output. Without these, this question is unanswerable. Please see [ask]

Comment: cell (OR2X4) {
  ##some scalar attributes such as (ex - cell_footprint : "OR2X4 ";)
  ## some attributes inside attributes 
            Ex – 
            (pg_pin (VDD) {
   voltage_name : "VDD";
   pg_type : "primary_power";
   timing () { ## some attributes values}
  })
So, I have many such cells inside my two files... I have to compare all the attributes of specific cell present in both files. 
So , For this I want to create a data structure containing all the parameters.. And Im stuck with how to do.. 
Please let me know if i have to make it more clear.

Comment: I have written previous code to first get the lines which contains details about particular cell, but Im getting all the lines below the line matching cells (\w+) { .. It might be a small problem, but as im new to perl, please help.

Comment: What language/format is the input in? This problem might already be solved for you.

Comment: See also [Perl Regexp Extract string from nested brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33939742/perl-regexp-extract-string-from-nested-brackets/33940217#33940217)

Comment: Maybe this module can be used: [`Parse::Liberty`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::Liberty)?

Comment: Can someone please help, how to write my code here... I always fall short of characters.

Answer (score 1):

I have to guess at your input data and therefor am not very sure about the problem and the goal.
But anyway, try changing your line

```
if ($line =~ /cell \(\w/../cell \(\w/) {
```

to

```
if ($line =~ /cell \(\w/..  $line =~/cell \(\w/) {
```

Otherwise the second regex will be matched against the uninitialised "$_".
I found this out by

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

which is one of my favorite tools.
By the way, you made me aware of this use of the range operator, which I find fascinating. Thanks.